# How can I extract values from XML and insert them into a table?

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I've got an XML file that I loaded into a XMLType variable and I want to extract the different values from several `.../ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData` nodes with different attribute values, and a `.../Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates` node, to insert them in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE LIE_GEOF
(
IDE_GEO VARCHAR2(24) NOT NULL,
COD_COM VARCHAR2(3) ,
COD_VIL VARCHAR2(5) ,
NOM_COM VARCHAR2(50) ,
ALT_MOY NUMBER(4,0) ,
SUP_HEC NUMBER(12,0) ,
NBR_POP NUMBER(10,0) ,
COD_ARR VARCHAR2(1) ,
COD_DEP VARCHAR2(2) ,
NOM_DEP VARCHAR2(30) ,
COD_REG VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
NOM_REG VARCHAR2(35) NOT NULL,
TXT_POL CLOB ,
CONSTRAINT LIE_GEOF_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDE_GEO) USING INDEX
);
```

The insertion must follow this rule :

- the values of the `/Document/Folder/Placemark/ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData` nodes with specific attribute values go into 11 first fields of the table.
- the value of node `/Document/Folder/Placemark/Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates` goes into the last field of the table (`TXT_POL`, which is a CLOB).

E.g. insert :

- COMMUNE00000000000000001 into `ID_GEOFLA`
- 216 into `COD_COM`
- ...
- 0.523147623541907,43.45799199978569 0.523016926446493,43.458214941462735... into `TXT_POL`

This my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="COMMUNE" id="COMMUNE">
<SimpleField name="ID_GEOFLA" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="CODE_COM" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="INSEE_COM" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="NOM_COM" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="STATUT" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="X_CHF_LIEU" type="int"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="Y_CHF_LIEU" type="int"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="X_CENTROID" type="int"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="Y_CENTROID" type="int"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="Z_MOYEN" type="int"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="SUPERFICIE" type="float"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="POPULATION" type="int"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="CODE_ARR" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="CODE_DEPT" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="NOM_DEPT" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="CODE_REG" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="NOM_REG" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>COMMUNE</name>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#COMMUNE">
<SimpleData name="ID_GEOFLA">COMMUNE00000000000000001</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_COM">216</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="INSEE_COM">32216</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_COM">LOURTIES-MONBRUN</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="STATUT">Commune simple</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CHF_LIEU">500820</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CHF_LIEU">6264958</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CENTROID">500515</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CENTROID">6265413</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Z_MOYEN">252</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="SUPERFICIE">966</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="POPULATION">139</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_ARR">3</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_DEPT">32</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_DEPT">GERS</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_REG">76</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_REG">LANGUEDOC-ROUSSILLON-MIDI-PYRENEES</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>0.523147623541907,43.45799199978569 0.523016926446493,43.458214941462735 0.522819929792566,43.458571384907614 0.523158712137025,43.463844819851531 0.525919177622142,43.466722549687468 0.534681879985461,43.464747550783542 0.543836737927885,43.469777335356682 0.548247371718109,43.472768370413348 0.550322756594321,43.477287979477317 0.551468474597506,43.478160877453561 0.552015304755935,43.478439663216299 0.552453497415003,43.478221827985358 0.555100797978036,43.474481276701823 0.555807213328205,43.473593492995199 0.558991284076016,43.472423990577127 0.56086273814842,43.472185286329086 0.564888471150887,43.471711436291166 0.566623349308327,43.471515470873307 0.567427459167519,43.471439009340536 0.568571543995261,43.468291800893347 0.569365669469214,43.464620982438333 0.567828019844389,43.460101271732199 0.567509757649282,43.458423540573534 0.567072440746275,43.458596443463989 0.566331570343829,43.458584307788286 0.562627166751401,43.458262522540728 0.560416690686975,43.457911246027962 0.559805673058565,43.457721968280353 0.554192459548327,43.459256113328266 0.551822357433493,43.460071196874786 0.549836876685425,43.460442173041024 0.548786602838374,43.460469727487656 0.548449080291229,43.459430568250141 0.548216275147381,43.458572899197428 0.549999653359123,43.456795920024497 0.550686563685562,43.456536916638157 0.553860511528465,43.456050548180549 0.555937760797512,43.456713991749211 0.55612105137207,43.45676223078474 0.556436817751908,43.456542525872251 0.556441991370131,43.456362621910301 0.555847087361284,43.455678628111059 0.552874026887119,43.453652001502725 0.551053529573104,43.452678364660322 0.550753210222253,43.452448351090517 0.550735797660037,43.451000593387143 0.550915991905762,43.449206264922303 0.553238100421676,43.447940984342978 0.553771683066166,43.447653300288636 0.554738707003582,43.44728268718503 0.56019111305528,43.444531605495072 0.562938636713414,43.443858069856788 0.56516268550633,43.443759562234121 0.567023409839381,43.443430527931177 0.566871862109568,43.442340715151943 0.566475653104936,43.44116529926356 0.566069176230466,43.440349687490794 0.564972682557216,43.439523066858889 0.564547029266048,43.439336180634278 0.562328585402901,43.439277281890504 0.559811880846763,43.438853383472782 0.557964223826497,43.438382404156521 0.557848915902549,43.438101676680482 0.557402040643657,43.436611852944097 0.556595818480535,43.436778188864331 0.550636409582979,43.43880112426811 0.546799103741674,43.440005028613726 0.543629269595757,43.4407612883318 0.543320674518776,43.44075609078584 0.54265340718862,43.440385418205821 0.542657248886231,43.440295495610123 0.540784834255311,43.440578841341114 0.539476542216563,43.44101538502607 0.537977690329699,43.441574496966403 0.537598849484849,43.441882721780303 0.525443080131764,43.448439347839923 0.523192997567408,43.452635557123507 0.522863538404974,43.455264457764613 0.523286197033435,43.457500103439656 0.523210047392157,43.457948420812656 0.523147623541907,43.45799199978569</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#COMMUNE">
<SimpleData name="ID_GEOFLA">COMMUNE00000000000000002</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_COM">033</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="INSEE_COM">47033</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_COM">BOUDY-DE-BEAUREGARD</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="STATUT">Commune simple</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CHF_LIEU">516424</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CHF_LIEU">6384852</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CENTROID">515575</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CENTROID">6385938</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Z_MOYEN">112</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="SUPERFICIE">1019</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="POPULATION">414</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_ARR">3</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_DEPT">47</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_DEPT">LOT-ET-GARONNE</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_REG">75</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_REG">AQUITAINE-LIMOUSIN-POITOU-CHARENTES</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>0.662777282430262,44.533218568792947 0.662625822063777,44.533683684987352 0.664135149761232,44.534301045766654 0.664601701741105,44.53474141714144 0.666067383219144,44.536202611177508 0.668371575237184,44.539071163388307 0.668780667988665,44.540111918933022 0.668694056305804,44.54132503082527 0.668237007094513,44.541902583263834 0.661102933562012,44.546525868685222 0.655808192025645,44.551625506724115 0.653467772380693,44.554175912637433 0.653141277604395,44.554576059140636 0.652486763179636,44.555442964276793 0.652183507746879,44.559674906105244 0.652050074453185,44.56203443873585 0.65262297218604,44.565978803821366 0.652985155710664,44.566479151724735 0.653173392380475,44.566527283736086 0.655703231649244,44.566071260198626 0.656280531260281,44.566124944124233 0.665861275263747,44.560864637649679 0.672258642298041,44.557309814039932 0.67799949907915,44.554599131975017 0.681452233083963,44.553121722329216 0.68225272878296,44.55371853273703 0.685712108726268,44.555884152916839 0.690569705466486,44.555408571617306 0.691265658733825,44.555238499982032 0.694383518064652,44.554026576432449 0.695593865542916,44.55350426999884 0.695528458077783,44.551435083497076 0.695086762394766,44.549358943255577 0.694945159859387,44.547737576530992 0.695346064664764,44.546925484921545 0.698073114077193,44.543795107633322 0.70046954041872,44.54119995483682 0.701115056066572,44.54062440044305 0.701895787889718,44.539727437699398 0.701898155870446,44.539638326402738 0.701585945597984,44.539543565425753 0.700850223013555,44.53890231681244 0.699442272579967,44.537576997853272 0.695904965284708,44.533386509441243 0.695362918653616,44.532569143918337 0.695030202600581,44.531034758336737 0.695924050526905,44.530172626698942 0.697096892400962,44.529260473371338 0.698441139658732,44.528342877669623 0.698635976884175,44.528165018106449 0.698670774882986,44.527403828815736 0.694169986184412,44.526478611374884 0.677305847476098,44.525695337096792 0.675878255066445,44.5250519592865 0.675502505745163,44.5248522134494 0.674807388781219,44.525162690384242 0.663037031530505,44.532783664990923 0.662777282430262,44.533218568792947</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#COMMUNE">
<SimpleData name="ID_GEOFLA">COMMUNE00000000000000003</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_COM">009</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="INSEE_COM">32009</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_COM">ARMOUS-ET-CAU</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="STATUT">Commune simple</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CHF_LIEU">472979</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CHF_LIEU">6278963</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CENTROID">473004</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CENTROID">6278937</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Z_MOYEN">221</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="SUPERFICIE">932</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="POPULATION">95</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_ARR">3</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_DEPT">32</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_DEPT">GERS</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_REG">76</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_REG">LANGUEDOC-ROUSSILLON-MIDI-PYRENEES</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>0.211253773793326,43.587275605450763 0.211662108609333,43.586825129365288 0.211410524399261,43.582088410940848 0.208388730598386,43.579871612218852 0.20791605570955,43.579277855019072 0.207747805004554,43.578816168736715 0.208179512909645,43.575542931484456 0.209504673568602,43.573834000361572 0.211507579682536,43.572497189496914 0.212150181576571,43.571835762135244 0.212220464219109,43.571612490215699 0.213304466304859,43.570734613884099 0.213572297332405,43.570191402028087 0.213343145301762,43.569377045441009 0.212477217367309,43.569360214746013 0.204382664237701,43.568630775264452 0.195504880892616,43.567919208267085 0.194771157076325,43.56768057328533 0.189887165282241,43.565695100853603 0.189464969023205,43.5654167771076 0.188573547265921,43.564455566501138 0.188277267038432,43.564134583389972 0.186022497178221,43.560097674244325 0.17965714473443,43.554240687039545 0.182359538159759,43.552852384226945 0.182962621356,43.552645664922274 0.182446681269315,43.552186618810737 0.18232300927318,43.552184308135637 0.168497898595728,43.554156277940244 0.16709367693472,43.5542654823644 0.167166420588363,43.555450395008101 0.167947100991704,43.566173754481518 0.169739934430584,43.568107590095238 0.17062790120118,43.569158906666985 0.170674775790308,43.569564373279157 0.170566743707011,43.570776093398251 0.170501036877491,43.571179526416337 0.170135040125033,43.572700537631427 0.169592574675525,43.573957655078644 0.168949458803322,43.574618831508829 0.161962656163579,43.579477358477909 0.161335403761748,43.5796896447509 0.161682881391107,43.580326261347274 0.165625298788884,43.580720060701331 0.167651845556293,43.579457563414131 0.172907376774138,43.579441484776346 0.178764502682293,43.580614811260261 0.183020836373061,43.587784790504855 0.190549481732969,43.588537141980531 0.191355477908399,43.588822688177068 0.191725286645556,43.589137463308489 0.192379775756839,43.589304741921623 0.198546721318716,43.588371923285642 0.210870974543736,43.587226159609642 0.211253773793326,43.587275605450763</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#COMMUNE">
<SimpleData name="ID_GEOFLA">COMMUNE00000000000000004</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_COM">225</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="INSEE_COM">38225</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_COM">AUTRANS-MEAUDRE EN VERCORS</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="STATUT">Commune simple</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CHF_LIEU">898640</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CHF_LIEU">6450689</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CENTROID">898625</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CENTROID">6451597</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Z_MOYEN">1234</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="SUPERFICIE">3371</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="POPULATION">2973</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_ARR">1</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_DEPT">38</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_DEPT">ISERE</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_REG">84</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_REG">AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>5.577223028135769,45.242894349342798 5.57832596943672,45.243222059527241 5.579405352743805,45.243371022191383 5.581393281318908,45.243366554489441 5.583879807369563,45.243609083543291 5.584393415224277,45.243684593379605 5.584706363164017,45.243585461644216 5.597939571410846,45.235202758388454 5.597932009534475,45.235067797149192 5.597735530497109,45.234983175547697 5.593525407710597,45.23032598100815 5.593407141698956,45.225917867030205 5.592935859647946,45.218549457778238 5.591818418919541,45.20665188726359 5.592324469084464,45.202045519989611 5.592360387984282,45.194616726820655 5.592062190466056,45.189869583881169 5.588405135802581,45.18315444315936 5.585955275660742,45.178063494435072 5.584708204811351,45.173935642642597 5.58317010835984,45.168083001649848 5.582929680649567,45.167235419723959 5.58266313119152,45.165712771343379 5.58222103751657,45.164689677638918 5.581670213054493,45.163986213256557 5.580207623453069,45.161160611061874 5.578947247375383,45.158519508031873 5.578785449469628,45.157938569461315 5.578466103115896,45.15551714841677 5.578405646819617,45.154483422388317 5.577928367445298,45.152832310190618 5.576422825654472,45.147519415266053 5.575055817042497,45.142306016064268 5.574010929727948,45.138442812442122 5.569886182007006,45.137293813512301 5.567431609863881,45.136644956438062 5.559512994676524,45.131968530965842 5.552488239743422,45.12523964839076 5.549925256615055,45.11918676788418 5.548942155727791,45.116267902375498 5.54809183826008,45.113636077924021 5.54304261824092,45.103915702437661 5.541186817821163,45.101484251797203 5.539607786090492,45.099233848807309 5.539254012339214,45.098614007454486 5.537988337271168,45.098695988165893 5.525330845617684,45.100291557757032 5.516559551312187,45.102076361315767 5.515673588077414,45.102146809640558 5.510960672585581,45.101436008987868 5.503655622743139,45.099816656819648 5.502498984104886,45.099579584852449 5.500714091434282,45.099486321764374 5.495946886320536,45.099486883613594 5.493215842703018,45.099511076201516 5.492329890741765,45.09958133898413 5.491964615581535,45.099861562497225 5.490817838869063,45.100929476693878 5.490763593578549,45.101110858312595 5.490769591583746,45.105927554983744 5.490833616150495,45.107050382628692 5.49194827048531,45.112421555600562 5.492205637544673,45.120704529973253 5.491850471979054,45.123640236865867 5.492087604562631,45.128044611271768 5.493441844917415,45.137774197940558 5.493606714068908,45.138445252930254 5.494173374852235,45.140589232267239 5.49584150526466,45.14442200079219 5.496571863993317,45.146066839051002 5.498716737985253,45.149336678837628 5.502331360906916,45.153834734559432 5.503709158680629,45.155685724457776 5.504333877845138,45.156613105210369 5.507363307441096,45.161981784085413 5.507996692262547,45.163269300471576 5.508157769366574,45.163850342151378 5.508790876733881,45.166037828080889 5.509806786947887,45.1684392178013 5.511570088791844,45.171513848793282 5.513801466466343,45.17539050162415 5.516535689990693,45.179734146853228 5.518638050551481,45.181978547224986 5.521184372654164,45.184966918788639 5.524699007997207,45.18933150609115 5.527267099507565,45.193264289042801 5.527552392296414,45.19379655621016 5.52798211441999,45.194760677516605 5.529131584243736,45.196902161978144 5.532065216609396,45.204074259159512 5.533315792715549,45.209305256325443 5.534246960643453,45.213644414855466 5.535652150394507,45.218902528006922 5.538852924686776,45.227250430001639 5.544802951534512,45.235190644397115 5.544935664193075,45.235276809833536 5.545374693549105,45.235174015847569 5.552065741575315,45.236835774382897 5.566478805561787,45.238372275208668 5.568866403881952,45.238356141784003 5.570284267242009,45.238630740324432 5.571836941242355,45.239035551975405 5.57462433441365,45.2402209101907 5.577077302110182,45.242583293815095 5.577223028135769,45.242894349342798</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#COMMUNE">
<SimpleData name="ID_GEOFLA">COMMUNE00000000000000005</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_COM">890</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="INSEE_COM">62890</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_COM">WILLEMAN</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="STATUT">Commune simple</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CHF_LIEU">640049</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CHF_LIEU">7028672</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="X_CENTROID">640115</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Y_CENTROID">7029900</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="Z_MOYEN">79</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="SUPERFICIE">1023</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="POPULATION">178</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_ARR">4</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_DEPT">62</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_DEPT">PAS-DE-CALAIS</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="CODE_REG">32</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="NOM_REG">NORD-PAS-DE-CALAIS-PICARDIE</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>2.151357610477108,50.342723579428736 2.150582398840049,50.343853128809613 2.150439420398362,50.344345961981944 2.147781898036236,50.348429901247719 2.144643960903647,50.352848920107654 2.142170362713468,50.354312287967623 2.139785273502974,50.354442932204655 2.139147310728909,50.356057285129864 2.136459688875384,50.361894178627317 2.136303634967463,50.362073550534305 2.136457891197435,50.362163514907749 2.143309717417935,50.367975295072092 2.149574739686743,50.375379804640581 2.151353800635636,50.377701211726055 2.152307917736184,50.378321866071232 2.155756214194353,50.379913059929052 2.154864354931062,50.380685355552338 2.155973798477377,50.381259457705227 2.156409086307008,50.380669881870404 2.157182705972685,50.37999822017963 2.158308050333875,50.379282265278022 2.159644626590358,50.378610832073001 2.166473449179359,50.37565036238319 2.167106098271396,50.375426588179472 2.167893230445291,50.375114070985006 2.168055448620143,50.374896996422471 2.168526372902896,50.37426272358401 2.169092409895663,50.373051795846251 2.169942448266939,50.370531964916502 2.170719245301723,50.368962416427962 2.175080979569476,50.369372312649269 2.183859825720376,50.370773789773402 2.18505079929214,50.370999825609218 2.185191902200479,50.370954968509238 2.18564361921614,50.370190318886401 2.184787545948869,50.370002412843633 2.183708661363136,50.369617304240514 2.182463727449356,50.36830454074083 2.181402963860765,50.366544971983508 2.182476664280656,50.364123484539761 2.185726357443533,50.356526912933504 2.186427269755563,50.356662618447764 2.186638577991434,50.356438655774838 2.187202454197396,50.355496954539362 2.188401939261542,50.353075312390636 2.186319206527587,50.348124388463035 2.184784410495321,50.343586432428438 2.184713679145266,50.343361503403536 2.18317169343704,50.343538954992638 2.166941973276032,50.344953195994378 2.152128396725606,50.342859066974349 2.151357610477108,50.342723579428736</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

What I tried so far is to extract the node value matching the attribute `ID_GEOFLA`; but this didn't work :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_xml (p_dir       IN  VARCHAR2,
                                  p_filename  IN  VARCHAR2) AS
l_bfile  BFILE := BFILENAME(p_dir, p_filename);
l_clob   CLOB;
xml_data xmltype;
ID_GEOFLA varchar2(255);   

BEGIN

DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE);
DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_clob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

xml_data :=XMLTYPE.createXML(l_clob);

for x in (

select a.ID  
from 
   XMLTABLE('/Document/Folder/Placemark/ExtendedData/SchemaData'
          PASSING xml_data
          COLUMNS ID VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//SimpleData/text()'

         ) a) loop
         dbms_output.put_line(x.ID);

         end loop;

  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_clob);

  END;
  /
```

How can I get the XML data into my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple Placemarks to you need the XMLTable XPath to refer to those; and then the column paths to refer to each node, specifying the attributes where relevant:

```
xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'),
    '/kml/Document/Folder/Placemark'
  passing xmltype(l_clob)
  columns ide_geo varchar2(24) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="ID_GEOFLA"]',
    cod_com varchar2(3) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_COM"]',
    cod_vil varchar2(5) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="INSEE_COM"]',
    nom_com varchar2(50) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="NOM_COM"]',
    alt_moy number(4,0) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="Z_MOYEN"]',
    sup_hec number(12,0) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="SUPERFICIE"]',
    nbr_pop number(10,0) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="POPULATION"]',
    cod_arr varchar2(1) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_ARR"]',
    cod_dep varchar2(2) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_DEPT"]',
    nom_dep varchar2(30) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="NOM_DEPT"]',
    cod_reg varchar2(2) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_REG"]',
    nom_reg varchar2(35) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="NOM_REG"]',
    txt_pol clob path 'Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates'
);
```

Also notice the inclusion of the `/kml` root node, and the declaration of a default namespace.

Adapting your procedure to use that with a CLOB loaded from a BFILE, and with a single `insert ... select` (no cursor loop required), you can do:

```
create or replace procedure load_xml (p_dir in  varchar2,
  p_filename  in  varchar2)
as
  l_clob clob;
  l_bfile bfile := bfilename(p_dir, p_filename);
  l_dest_offset pls_integer := 1;
  l_src_offset pls_integer := 1;
  l_lang_context pls_integer := 0;
  l_warning pls_integer;
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary (l_clob, true);
  dbms_lob.fileopen(l_bfile, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
  dbms_lob.loadclobfromfile(dest_lob=>l_clob,
    src_bfile=>l_bfile,
    amount=>dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
    dest_offset=>l_dest_offset,
    src_offset=>l_src_offset,
    bfile_csid=>0,
    lang_context=>l_lang_context,
    warning=>l_warning);
  dbms_lob.fileclose(l_bfile);

  insert into lie_geof (ide_geo, cod_com, cod_vil, nom_com, alt_moy, sup_hec,
    nbr_pop, cod_arr, cod_dep, nom_dep, cod_reg, nom_reg, txt_pol)
  select ide_geo, cod_com, cod_vil, nom_com, alt_moy, sup_hec,
    nbr_pop, cod_arr, cod_dep, nom_dep, cod_reg, nom_reg, txt_pol
  from xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'),
    '/kml/Document/Folder/Placemark'
    passing xmltype(l_clob)
    columns ide_geo varchar2(24) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="ID_GEOFLA"]',
      cod_com varchar2(3) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_COM"]',
      cod_vil varchar2(5) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="INSEE_COM"]',
      nom_com varchar2(50) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="NOM_COM"]',
      alt_moy number(4,0) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="Z_MOYEN"]',
      sup_hec number(12,0) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="SUPERFICIE"]',
      nbr_pop number(10,0) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="POPULATION"]',
      cod_arr varchar2(1) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_ARR"]',
      cod_dep varchar2(2) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_DEPT"]',
      nom_dep varchar2(30) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="NOM_DEPT"]',
      cod_reg varchar2(2) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="CODE_REG"]',
      nom_reg varchar2(35) path 'ExtendedData/SchemaData/SimpleData[@name="NOM_REG"]',
      txt_pol clob path 'Polygon/outerBoundaryIs/LinearRing/coordinates'
  );

  dbms_lob.freetemporary (l_clob);
end;
/
```

... which when run with your file gets:

```
select * from lie_geof;

IDE_GEO                  COD COD_V NOM_COM                                               ALT_MOY    SUP_HEC    NBR_POP C CO NOM_DEP                        CO NOM_REG                             TXT_POL                                                                         
------------------------ --- ----- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- - -- ------------------------------ -- ----------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMUNE00000000000000001 216 32216 LOURTIES-MONBRUN                                          252        966        139 3 32 GERS                           76 LANGUEDOC-ROUSSILLON-MIDI-PYRENEES  0.523147623541907,43.45799199978569 0.523016926446493,43.458214941462735 0.52281
COMMUNE00000000000000002 033 47033 BOUDY-DE-BEAUREGARD                                       112       1019        414 3 47 LOT-ET-GARONNE                 75 AQUITAINE-LIMOUSIN-POITOU-CHARENTES 0.662777282430262,44.533218568792947 0.662625822063777,44.533683684987352 0.6641
COMMUNE00000000000000003 009 32009 ARMOUS-ET-CAU                                             221        932         95 3 32 GERS                           76 LANGUEDOC-ROUSSILLON-MIDI-PYRENEES  0.211253773793326,43.587275605450763 0.211662108609333,43.586825129365288 0.2114
COMMUNE00000000000000004 225 38225 AUTRANS-MEAUDRE EN VERCORS                               1234       3371       2973 1 38 ISERE                          84 AUVERGNE-RHONE-ALPES                5.577223028135769,45.242894349342798 5.57832596943672,45.243222059527241 5.57940
COMMUNE00000000000000005 890 62890 WILLEMAN                                                   79       1023        178 4 62 PAS-DE-CALAIS                  32 NORD-PAS-DE-CALAIS-PICARDIE         2.151357610477108,50.342723579428736 2.150582398840049,50.343853128809613 2.1504
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! The problem now is that my real file is 119 megabytes and the script has been running for more than 3 hours and I really think that it is completely unwise to use it in a production environment...

Comment: Presumably that amount of data won't be loaded and parsed often though? You could (maybe somewhere else) run the query part in a loop without doing the insert, to see how much of the time us being spent on the XML and how much on the insert. Your DBA might be able to advise on any bottlenecks. Another option might be to split the XML into CSV, say, and then load as an external table or through SQL\*Loader - but the final CLOB column makes that tricky, assuming it can actually be more than 4k.